# Avoid a lot of if - else checks - Choose table from string using the entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing an app with Entity Framework.
I've got a combo box with the names of the tables in the database.
I have the following code:

```
string table = cbTables.SelectedItem.ToString();
using (var dbContext = new Entities()) {
    if (table.Equals("Person")) {
        List<Person> list = (from l in dbContext.People select l).ToList();
    } else if (table.Equals("Student")) {
        List<Student> list = (from u in dbContext.Student select u).ToList();
    } else if (table.Equals("Grade")) {
        List<Grade> list = (from p in dbContext.Grade select p).ToList();
}
```

how can i avoid all these if-else checks?
Is it possible to get the name of a class from a string holding the name?

example:

```
string = "Person";
var str = //something
List<str> list = (from u in dbContext.str select u).ToList();
```

Comment: What are you doing with the list afterwards? This may well affect the answer.

Comment: `Dictionary<string,DbSet>`?

Comment: I'm opening a new form with a data grid view showing the whole table.

Comment: What's the output you really need? IList?

Comment: @tia I just need to store the table in some structure and to show it in a data grid view in a new windows form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBox` is capable of displaying dictionary through the datasource, so you can bind display text with the data you actually want instead of checking the display text. Then in this case we would bind it to the type of the entity:

```
Dictionary<string,Type> typeMap = new Dictionary<string,Type> {
    { "Person", typeof(Person) },
    { "Student", typeof(Student) },
    { "Grade", typeof(Grade) },
}
```

then bind it to `ComboBox` like:

```
cbTables.DataSource = new BindingSource(typeMap, null);
cbTables.DisplayMember = "Key";
cbTables.ValueMember = "Value";
```

then, when you need to get selected entity, use

```
Type entityType = (Type) cbTables.SelectedValue;
DbSet set = dbContext.Set(entityType);
```

However, after this you need to inspect `entityType` and display the form accordingly. If your form needs List e.g. List, then use

```
List<Student> studentList = set.Cast<Student>.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want a switch but you want something dynamic, you can use queries instead:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var people = context.Database.SqlQuery<Object>(
                       "select * from People").ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without sql queries?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment:

You can declare a dictionary to map from the string of your table name to the actual DbSet that is your table:

```
string table = cbTables.SelectedItem.ToString();
using (var dbContext = new Entities()) {
    Dictionary<string, DbSet> mapping = new Dictionary<string, DbSet> {
        { "Person", dbContext.Person },
        { "Student", dbContext.Student },
        { "Grade", dbContext.Grade }
    };

    //...
```

The problem will remain - what to do with your result set? Right now you have typed lists with the specific type of each table's members; you won't be able to do that without a decision (if/switch) of some sort.

Comment: you could do the same thing for types
"new Dictionary<string, Type>", and use Convert.ChangeType to change it

Comment: @ron Dictionary<string, Type> dict = new Dictionary<string, Type> { {"Person", Person } }; gives an error: Person is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @john, you'd have to use Dictionary<string, Type> dict = new Dictionary<string, Type> { {"Person", typeof(Person) } };

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using Switch for this purpose?

```
string table = cbTables.SelectedItem.ToString();

using (var dbContext = new Entities()) 
{
    switch (table)
    {
        case"Person":
            List<Person> list = (from l in dbContext.People select l).ToList();
            break;
        case"Student":
            List<Student> list = (from u in dbContext.Student select u).ToList();
            break;
        case"Grade":
            List<Grade> list = (from p in dbContext.Grade select p).ToList();
            break;
    }
}
```